# How can I write a degree symbol in rmarkdown2 for HTML and PDF output?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I want to write a degree symbol in an rmarkdown file that is rendered correctly both for HTML and PDF output. A regular `°` works for HTML, and a `$^\circ$` works for the PDF - but what works for both cases?

Comment: `"\u00b0"` as R output?

Answer (score 51):

Use `&deg;` i.e. `75&deg;F` turns into 75°F in both HTML and PDF outputs.